# How do probability measures on $\mathbb{Z}$ look like?

Tags: measure-theory, amenability

Let $\mu: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a finitely additive $\mathbb{Z}$-invariant probability measure on $\mathbb{Z}$. Such measures exist because $\mathbb{Z}$ is [amenable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group) and one can indeed describe examples of such measures as ultralimits of sequences of asymptotic densities computed with respect to a Følner sequence; for example, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967207/finitely-additive-shift-invariant-probability-measure-on-z) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/12281/33039).

I have two questions which I hope are elementary, but I was not able to figure out.

1. Does $\mu$ have to generalize the notion of asymptotic density of a subset of integers? In other words, does $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|A \cap [-n,n]|}{2n+1}=r$ imply that $\mu(A)=r$? The answer is clearly yes for infinite arithmetic progressions by finite additivity of $\mu$. On the other hand, sets of integers with asymptotic density can look very different than such sets, so I do not see how to extend the result to these sets.
2. $\mu$ is necessarily not continuous from above or below; otherwise it would be a $\sigma$-additive measure as shown, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406264/a-finitely-additive-measure-is-measure-if-and-only-if-continuous-from-below). Indeed, we have that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(\mathbb{Z}-[-n,n]) = 1 \neq 0 = \mu\left(\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}-[-n,n]\right)$. My question this time is a bit vague. Is it possible to give a (useful) sufficient condition for a class of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ that guarantees the continuity of $\mu$ from above and below for sequences in this class? This would allow us to compute the probability of infinitely many events happening simultaneously in certain cases.

Perhaps I should mention the motivation behind this question. It is often written that "there is no way to choose an integer at random" due to the lack of a $\sigma$-additive measure on $\mathbb{Z}$ which chooses each integer with equal probability. But there are **finitely** additive such measures. So why don't we use these measures to model the situations where we need to choose an integer at random? If we are to do that, such measures need to satisfy certain intuitive properties; for example, it needs to generalize asymptotic density (hence my first question) and it should satisfy some basic identities that allow us to play with it (hence my second question).

---

**Some more motivation**: Let me also add how I ended up thinking about this in the first place. It is well-known that the probability that two randomly chosen integers from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ are coprime goes to $6/\pi^2$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Let us try formalize the idea given in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Probability_of_coprimality) Wikipedia article using such a measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and try to exactly prove that "two randomly chosen integers are coprime with probability $6/\pi^2$."

Let $\mu: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a finitely additive $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$-variant probability measure. For each prime $p$, set $A_p=\{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}: p \nmid a \text{ or } p \nmid b\}$. Then, finite additivity implies that $\mu(A_p)=1-\frac{1}{p^2}$ for any prime $p$. It follows that

$$\mu(\{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}: gcd(m,n)=1\})=\mu\left(\bigcap_{p \text{ prime}} A_p\right) \leq \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \mu(A_p)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}$$

The lack of continuity of $\mu$ from above prevents us to conclude equality as it may be that $\prod_{p \text{ prime}} \mu(A_p)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mu(A_2 \cap A_3 \cap \dots \cap A_{p_n}) \neq \mu\left(\bigcap_{p \text{ prime}} A_p\right)$. This is partly why I am interested in the second question; I'd be happy to see if this were actually equality, which, we know in our hearts, must be true!

Clearly the specific problem here regarding coprimality is just a distraction. What I really want to see is if "taking limits of probabilities obtained on the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$" actually corresponds to something meaningful in this finitely additive setting.

Comment: If your finitely additive measure gives an equal positive measure (proportional to likelihood of selection) to each element of $\mathbb Z$ then there is no limit to what this measure adds up for finite subsets of $\mathbb Z$ and so cannot be usefully used to choose each integer with equal probability

Comment: @Henry: For any such measure $\mu$, we have $\mu(F)=0$ for every finite subset $F \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. So yes, the probability that we choose a certain integer is always $0$. Why does this make it not useful? The same holds for, say, the uniform measure on $[0,1]$. But it is pretty useful, isn't it?

Comment: I would probably say that continuous distributions like $U[0,1]$ are useful because they assign nonzero probabilities to intervals, and so can be used to select a random real to within any desired precision.  (That is, even though you’ve still got a continuum of possible values, they’re all close together.). Here you don’t get that... in fact, the opposite, since the values contained in nested subsets are ever farther apart.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: If you are thinking of the closed intervals as "building-blocks to approximate numbers" in $[0,1]$, I believe the correct counterpart here would be infinite arithmetic progressions, which have the expected measure. So to specify an integer $n$ with "arbitrary precision", we specify various $(a,b)$ with $b \equiv n\ (mod\ a)$. The more $(a,b)$ we specify, the better "approximation" we get.

Comment: That’s an interesting idea - it’s almost like your putting a measure on the Adele ring or something. Unfortunately, I don’t think it’s that useful for normal applications since the random variable defined by such a measure won’t have finite mean or variance.

Comment: You seem to define "$\mu$ generalizes asymptotic density" to mean that $$\mu(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap[-n,n]|}{2n+1}$$ whenever the limit exists. Shouldn't it rather be the stronger condition that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap[-n,n]|}{2n+1}\le\mu(A)\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap[-n,n]|}{2n+1}$$ for all $A\subseteq\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @bof: Sure, we can use lower and upper densities to state the question. I guess I required less since I was really hoping the answer to be positive, which seems not to be the case. So, instead of working with arbitrary such $\mu$, I think I'd rather work with one obtained as an ultralimit of densities, in which case the stronger requirement should also be satisfied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let me answer your general question about using these means to generate uniform distributions on $\mathbb{Z}$. These finitely additive measures look like Radon measures on $\beta \mathbb{Z}$. Using set theoretical arguments, you can cook up $2^{2^{|\mathbb Z|}}$ different closed $\mathbb{Z}$-invariant subsets in $\beta \mathbb{Z}$, each of which is able to support a different invariant measure by Day's fixed point theorem. So the first problem in generating uniform random numbers in $\mathbb{Z}$ is choosing one of the $2^{2^{|\mathbb{Z}|}}$ different finitely additive probabilities that $\mathbb{Z}$ admits.

Your question hints at using the partial Cèsaro means $\mu_n = \frac{1}{2n+1} \sum_{k=-n}^n \delta_k$; indeed, this is reasonable as any $w^*$-cluster point of $\mu_n$ can be seen to be a finitely additive invariant probability on $\mathbb{Z}$. However, when you implement this in practice, it's unclear how this would be any different from a discrete uniform distribution on a large, but finite, subset of $\mathbb{Z}$.

The answer to your first listed question is no. Notice that each invariant finitely additive probability corresponds to an invariant norm-one linear functional on $\ell^\infty (\mathbb{Z})$. Observe that by a careful use of the Hahn-Banach theorem, the functionals $L_+(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}x_n$ and $L_-(x) = \lim_{n \to -\infty}(x_n)$ can be extended to two distinct Banach limits $B_+$ and $B_-$. To each, we associate the probability $\mu_{\pm}$, which we calculate via $\mu_{\pm}(A) = B_{\pm}(\chi_A)$. Setting $A = \mathbb{Z}^+$, we observe that $\mu_+(A) = 1$, $\mu_-(A) = 0$, but neither is $0.5$, which is the asymptotic density of $A$. That said, by dropping to a subnet, the claim about asymptotic density does hold for any finitely additive probability that arises as the $w^*$-cluster point of the partial Cèsaro means sequence.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see that the extension given by Hahn-Banach is also $\mathbb{Z}$-invariant (i.e. shift invariant), except going through the proof and seeing that it is, presumably, as $L_+$ is?

Comment: In general, translation invariance is not preserved by Hahn-Banach extensions. You would have to look at the proof of this statement to see why this is the case.