# Is it possible to define a "uniform" probability space on $\mathbb N$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Is it possible to define "uniform" probability on $\mathbb N$? I first thought that it is intuitively "clear" how the probability density is defined. Consider the following examples:

Example 1. Probability of choosing an even number has probability 1/2.

Example 2. Probability of choosing a multiple of 3 has probability 1/3.

However, more thoughts revealed that my initial postulation is wrong. By contradiction, if there is such probability density function, then $P(X \leq n) = 0$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$, which means that Density and cumulative distribution functions are 0. This doesn't make sense at all! (It is also possible to choose a set $A \subset \mathbb N$ with $|A| = \infty$ and $\frac{|[n] \cap A|}{[n]} \rightarrow 0$, where $[n] = \{1, \cdots, n\}$.)

So what went wrong? How can I define a sigma algebra and probability measure so that the event space behaves similar to uniform distribution so that

1. $P$(Even numbers) = 1/2
2. $P$(Multiples of 3) = 1/3?

Comment: You should read on sets of measure zero. You won't be able to define a uniform distribution on N like this.

Comment: There is no uniform probability measure on $\mathbb N$. See however [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density).

Comment: actually, I found a good article: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10959-015-0611-2. I will take a look at this one.

Comment: @PaulPogba See also [“Uniform probability” on a set of naturals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47134/uniform-probability-on-a-set-of-naturals) on MO.

Comment: @dxiv: The paper just mentioned should be included as an answer to the question you linked, since it postdates the last activity on that question by 5 years.

Comment: @PaulPogba There is a sense in which this can be done, although you won't obtain a true $\sigma$-additive measure. Look for the "amenability" tag and see, for instance, this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4131840/how-do-probability-measures-on-mathbbz-look-like/

Comment: @PeterO. True, I wasn't paying attention to the chronology. Left a comment on MO linking to the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of positive integers, let $X$ be a random variable defined on $\mathbb{N}$, and for each $k\in N$, let $p_{\vphantom{\frac{1}{1}}k}=P(X=k)$.

It's clear that $X$ can't be truly uniform else we would have
$$
0 < p_1=p_2=p_3=\cdots
$$
but then for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we would have
$$
P(X\le n)=np_1
$$
which exceeds $1$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Moreover we can show

**Claim:**

It is not possible to define $p_1,p_2,p_3,...$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have 
$$
P(A_n)=\frac{1}{n}
$$
where $A_n$ is the event that $X$ is a multiple of $n$.

**Proof:**

Suppose otherwise.

Let $Q$ be the set of prime numbers, and for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $Q_k=\{q\in Q{\,\mid\,}q > k\}$.

From the fact that
$$
\prod_{\large{q\in Q}}\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{q}\Bigr)=0
$$
it follows that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
$$
\prod_{\large{q\in Q_k}}\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{q}\Bigr)=0
$$
Now if $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ are such that $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then
$$
P(A_m\cap A_n)
=
P(A_{mn})
=
\frac{1}{mn}
=
\frac{1}{m}{\,\cdot\,}\frac{1}{n}
=
P(A_m)P(A_n)
$$
so $A_m,A_n$ are independent.

Then for all $k\in N$ we have
$$
p_k
\le
\prod_{\large{q\in Q_k}}\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{q}\Bigr)
=
0
$$
contrary to
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_{\vphantom{\frac{1}{1}}k}=1
$$
which completes the proof of the claim.

Comment: I am unsure about the last two lines. By $p_k$, do you mean $p_k = P(X = k)$?

Comment: $p_k = 0$, so $p_k \leq \prod_{q \in Q_k} (1-1/q)$ trivially. Or perhaps, you meant $p_k = P(A_k)$, where $A_k$ is the set of multiples of $k$.

Comment: @Paul Pogba: I$\,$ *defined* $\,p_k = P(X = k)$, and then I$\,$ *proved* $\,$that $p_k=0$ for all $k$, which contradicts the requirement that $\sum p_k=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If we take out the singletons $\{\{n\} \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ from the $\sigma$-algebra (more precisely, the event space $\mathcal F \subset 2^\mathbb N$ contains no finite set), then there is no contradiction since $p_n$ is undefined for every $n \in \mathbb N$. Note that $\mathcal F$ contains events such as "the set of all multiples of $n$" or "the set of all primes."

Comment: @Paul Pogba:  In order to have a distribution which allows for selecting random positive integers, the probabilities $p_1,p_2,p_3,...$ must be defined.

Comment: @Paul Pogba: Furthernore, if $A_n$ denotes the set of positive integers which are multiples of $n$, then any $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{N}$ which contains $A_1,A_2,A_3,...\,$ *must* $\,$contain all singleton subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yes, I get your idea, while I think a more interesting conversation can be made if we replace countably additivity by finite additivity.

Comment: Paul Pogba: Sure, but the objective of my post was to show that there does not exist an actual probability distribution on $\mathbb{N}$ such that $P(A_n)={\large{\frac{1}{n}}}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.-