Understanding the range of a strange finitely additive measure
I came across the following example.
Let $\mu_0$ be a finitely additive probability measure defined on every subset of $\mathbb N$ such that $\mu_0(A)=0$ if $A$ is finite. For $n \geq 1$, let $\mu_n$ be point mass at $n$, i.e. the probability measure defined for every subset of $\mathbb N$ by $\mu_n(\{n\})=1$. Let
$$\mu = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \mu_n$$
Claim $\mu$ does not take the value $1/2$.
Here's what I see. If $A$ is finite, then $\mu_0(A)=0$ and $\sum_{n \geq 1} 1/2^{n+1} \mu_n(A) < 1/2$ because all but finitely many terms in the series are $0$, so $\mu(A) < 1/2$. If $A$ is co-finite, then $\mu_0(A)=1$ and $\sum_{n \geq 1} 1/2^{n+1} \mu_n(A) > 0$ because infinitely many terms in the series are positive, so $\mu(A) > 1/2$.
How to conclude for infinite $A$ with infinite complement? I guess I'm failing to grasp something about the possible values that sub-series of $\sum_{n \geq 1} 1/2^{n+1}$ can take.
Added. The reasoning above goes through for the case where $\mu_0(A)=0$, whether or not $A$ is finite, and the case where $\mu_0(A)=1$, whether or not $A$ is co-finite. So, really, my question is how to conclude when $\mu_0(A) \in (0,1)$.

This violates my intuition. Let $E$ and $O$ be the sets of even and odd (respectively) positive integers. Can't we define finitely additive probability measures $\mu_E$ and $\mu_O$ on $E$ and $O$ individually that are zero on finite subsets? Then isn't $\mu_0 = \frac13\mu_E + \frac23\mu_O$ a finitely additive probability measure on $\Bbb N$ with the same property? If so, this $\mu_0$ takes the value $\frac12$ on each of $E$ and $O$.

@GregMartin I'm not sure I follow your intuition, but in any case the claim is about $\mu$, not $\mu_0$. The example allows that $\mu_0$ takes the value $1/2$.

This seems a little odd, because finitely additive measures on the integers are not that hard to come by; see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4131840/how-do-probability-measures-on-mathbbz-look-like/4133082#4133082.  Where does this exercise come from?  Are you sure this is correct?

@aduh That was a typo, I meant that $\mu$ itself takes the value $\frac12$ on each of $E$ and $O$.

@MikhailKatz This is Example 11.4.1 in the book Theory of Charges: A Study of Finitely Additive Measures

In view of Bruno's answer, what about the example 11.4.1?

@MikhailKatz As far as I can see, the claim in the example is false. Perhaps the authors meant to say that $\mu_0$ is 0-1 valued.

If you asked them about it, I am curious to know what they say; in such case, keep me posted.

A generalised limit will be defined as an extension of the classical limit functional $(a_n)_n \mapsto \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ from the space of convergent sequences to the whole of $\ell^\infty$ with operator norm $1$.
You can refer to this forum post by Terence Tao for more information on generalised limits, and Chapter VII of Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces by Diestel for an account on the (linear isometric surjective) correspondence between finitely additive measures and the dual of $\ell^\infty$, of the form:
$$\mu \leftrightarrow L$$
$$\|\mu\|_{TV} = \|L\|_{(\ell^\infty)^*}$$
$$\mu(E) = L(1_E)$$
$$L(u) = \int_{\mathbb{N}} u\mathrm{d}\mu$$
where $1_E$ is the indicator sequence of $E$ and $\|\cdot\|_{TV}$ the total variation norm.
One can prove two facts:

The aforementioned correspondence induces another correspondence between finitely additive, positive, probability measures vanishing on finite sets and generalised limits (this is based on a careful study of said correspondence);
For any divergent sequence $u$ and any $\alpha \in [\liminf u, \limsup u]$, one can define a generalised limit $L$ such that $L(u) = \alpha$ (this is an application of the Hahn-Banach theorem).

It then suffices to take any set such that $1_E$ diverges, $E := 2\mathbb{N}$ for example, and choose a generalised limit $L_0$ such that: $$L_0(1_E) = 1 - \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\mu_n(E)}{2^n} \in [0,1] = [\liminf 1_E, \limsup 1_E]$$
It is then evident that, if $\mu_0$ is the measure corresponding to $L_0$, we have:
$$\mu(E) = \frac{1}{2} \mu_0(E) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\mu_n(E)}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2} \left(1 - \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\mu_n(E)}{2^n} + \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\mu_n(E)}{2^n}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$$
thus disproving your claim as it stands.

Thanks! All the stuff about generalised limits is somewhat superfluous, but I think you have the right idea, which I missed. Namely, start with a finitely additive, two-valued measure $\mu_0$ on the finite/co-finite algebra, and then extend to some $E$ so that $\mu_0(E) = 1 - \sum_{n \geq 1} \mu_n(E)/2^n$ (this is the trick I missed). This is possible because the span of $E$'s inner and outer $\mu_0$ measure will be $[0,1]$.

@aduh Well, it wasn't superfluous for me as I'm more accustomed to the linear functional point of view and that's how I learned about finitely additive measures, but I do appreciate that there is a more direct path that you were able to find. You could make it an answer of your own!

Sorry, didn't mean to be dismissive. It all comes to the same thing, I think. The existence of the generalized limit is equivalent to the measure extension that I mentioned in my comment.

@aduh Well, sorry if it seemed like I thought you were dismissive, it's my bad really. Have a nice day/night!
